# Should all initialization code be restricted to the Initialize method?

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, so I wanted to know if it's ok if I'm initalizing the object in the load content method instead of the initialize method? Is it really important?
Thanks.

BTW the reason I'm asking this question is because that I have to load the texture before I intialize my player object, and I can't think of possible way to do it except this way.

If anyone has an idea what should I do, It'd be great, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to create objects with new in the `LoadContent` method. You can load content everywhere else *[after `Game.LoadContent` is called -AR]*, too.

Xna is only providing a pattern with there `Initialize` and `LoadContent` methods. If you want to keep it, add `LoadContent` method to your player object and call it from your Game `LoadContent` method (or use a drawable game component for your player).

**Edit:**

Here is an example using a DrawableGameComponent:

*Player.cs*

```
class Player : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public Player(Game game) : base(game)
    {
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
       // ... load your content via Game.Content.Load<...>(...);
    }
}
```

*Game.cs*

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    Components.Add(new Player(this));
}
```

Comment: People create objects in the load content often? Or it's rare? When I said with the "new" I meant this way: MyPlayer = new Player(); And what do you mean by saying "You can load content everywhere else?" You mean in other classes?

Comment: It's only a pattern. If you want to keep the pattern, derive your player class from DrawableGameComponent and at it to Game.Components.

Comment: I've added a note to your answer: you should only load graphics content (`Texture2D`, etc) during and after `LoadContent`. Before that point the graphics device is not ready. ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.loadcontent.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

In my games, I don't ever user the initialize method. The reason for that is I actually find inconsistency in what methods get called and when. So in my LoadContent() method, I construct the object and the constructor loads what ever textures it needs in it own method that I hand it. So you will have the texture when the the player is done constructing.

It honestly doesn't matter what order you init or load content in, you should just be consistent because thats good code. (or easier to read)`